# How to validate on some persistence actions, but not others

Tags: spring, validation, jpa, spring-boot

I've got a requirement that states a user can 'save' a `foo` with no validation at all, but if they 'submit' then the object must be validated.  I've got this all built and working on the front-end with Parsley.js, but want to add back-end validation.

What is the typical approach to doing this with Spring/Boot?  I understand the basic JPA validation, but I don't know how to apply it conditionally.

I want to also mention I tried to do this with 2 subclasses of `Foo`, but I'm unable to manage switching types, either because it's not possible in Java, or because I don't understand how you can instantiate a new version of the object and expect it to `.equals()` the old version for Hibernate persistence.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear on your terminology and perhaps give some pseudocode demonstrating what you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use JSR 303 [Validation Groups](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups). This gives you conditional validation.
2. Use Spring's [@Validated](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) in your handler methods. This lets you apply different validations in your Controllers
3. Follow my example here: http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/06/draft-entities-hibernate-validator.html

Comment: Excellent advice.  Can you suggest how I can write a unit test to ensure that my controller rejects the record?

Answer (score 0):

JPA has no possibility for conditional validations.

Why? Because many validations are just database constraints that are not validated by JPA, but unconditionally by the database.

For example a

```
@NotNull
private Integer value;
```

will create a column with a `NOT NULL` constraint.

Or a

```
@Size(max = 100)
private String value;
```

will create a column of `VARCHAR(100)`

As you might understand it is not possible to save a value into such a column that breaks the size constraint and has more than 100 characters.

And indeed - it is not possible to *switch* the type of an object in Java.

You can cast for example a `Entity1` to `Entity2`, but that is only the variable for the compiler. The object itself is an `Entity1` - no matter what you try. But you can *copy* all values from an instance of `Entity1` to a new instance of `Entity2`:

```
Entity1 entity1 = ...
Entity2 entity2 = new Entity2();
entity2.setProperty(entity1.getProperty());
...
entityManager.persist(entity2);
entityManager.delete(entity1);
```

If you don't like to copy all the properties by hand, you could use `BeanUtils.copyProperties` from [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils).

Comment: Does copying properties as you've described allow for adequate .equals() comparisons for entity persistence?  That is, with the assumption that I pair down the .equals() method to only compare attr values and not Id/timestamp

Comment: I forgot about bean validation - so I would say that Neil McGuigans answer is better than mine - better try to use that one.